# Unreal Engine 4 - How to avoid blocking game thread when saving file to storage

Tags: multithreading, unreal-engine4

I'm working on a gearvr app and trying to download an mp4 (aprox 250mb) and save it to the device.

It seems the save operation blocks the game thread, which causes the rendering to freeze for a few seconds, while the gearvr IMU remains active. The result is that the game freezes and you basically end up being able to look around a frozen quad :/

My download and save code is:

```
request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindLambda([&](FHttpRequestPtr request, FHttpResponsePtr response, bool success) {
        if (!success) {
            return;
        }

        TArray<uint8> data = response->GetContent();
        FString path = FPaths::Combine(FPaths::GamePersistentDownloadDir(), "video.mp4");
        FBufferArchive archive;
        archive << data;

        success = FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(archive, *path);

        if (success) {
            UGameplayStatics::OpenLevel(GetWorld(), "Player");
        }
    });
```

Since the downloading operation itself does not seem to be the one blocking the UI, I assume it would be either the insertion operator `archive << data` or `SaveArrayToFile`. So I tried doing both operations on a separate thread, like so:

```
ACard::ACard() {
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // ...

    request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindLambda([&](FHttpRequestPtr request, FHttpResponsePtr response, bool success) {
        GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 2.f,
            success ? FColor::Green : FColor::Red,
            success ? TEXT("download successful") : TEXT("download failed"));

        if (!success) {
            return;
        }

        task = Task::dispatch([response]() {
            FBufferArchive archive;
            TArray<uint8> data = response->GetContent();
            archive << data;

            FString path = FPaths::Combine(FPaths::GamePersistentDownloadDir(), "video.mp4");
            FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile(archive, *path);
        });

        SetActorTickEnabled(true);
    });
}

void ACard::BeginPlay() {
    Super::BeginPlay();
    SetActorTickEnabled(false);
}

void ACard::Tick( float DeltaTime ) {
    Super::Tick( DeltaTime );

    if (task && task->complete) {
        SetActorTickEnabled(false);
        UGameplayStatics::OpenLevel(GetWorld(), "Player");
    }
}
```

Where `Task` is defined like so:

```
class  Task : public FRunnable {

private:
    TFunction<void()> task;
    FRunnableThread* thread;

public:
    bool complete{ false };

    static Task* dispatch(TFunction<void()> task) {
        auto newInstance = new Task(task);

        newInstance->thread = FRunnableThread::Create(
            newInstance,
            TEXT(""),
            0,
            TPri_BelowNormal
        );

        return newInstance;
    }

    Task(TFunction<void()> task) : task(task) {}
    bool Init() override { return true; }
    void Stop() override {}

    uint32 Run() override {
        task();
        complete = true;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

But the above seems to make no difference: Saving the file still blocks the UI for about 3secs.
So my question is: how should I be saving the file to storage without blocking the game itself?

UPDATE:

This issue is still not resolved. Following the advice in one of the comments below, I added logs to check that the code does indeed execute on separate threads and it does. The logs are consistent with the actions:

1. Dispatch save task from game thread.
2. execute task (save) in background thread.
3. dispatch new task to load the next level from background thread.
4. execute new task (load next level) from game thread.

Yet the UI thread still blocks.

```
01 - 18 19:59 : 10.404 18059 18075 D UE4 : LogTemp:Warning: Dispatch TASK : tID 18075 | is game ? 1
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.404 18059 18075 D UE4 : [2017.01.19 - 00.59.10:415][-8608252]LogTemp : Warning : Dispatch TASK : tID 18075 | is game ? 1
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.414 18059 18259 D UE4 : LogTemp:Warning: Execute TASK : tID 18259 | is game ? 0
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.414 18059 18075 D UE4 : [2017.01.19 - 00.59.10:419][-8608252]LogTemp : Warning : Execute TASK : tID 18259 | is game ? 0
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.524 18059 18140 I OVR : PhoneManagerThread - phone running!nfds = 1
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.524 18059 18259 D UE4 : LogTemp:Warning: Dispatch TASK : tID 18259 | is game ? 0
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 10.524 18059 18075 D UE4 : [2017.01.19 - 00.59.10:536][-8608252]LogTemp : Warning : Dispatch TASK : tID 18259 | is game ? 0
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 11.064 18059 18075 D UE4 : LogTemp:Warning: Execute TASK : tID 18075 | is game ? 1
01 - 18 19 : 59 : 11.064 18059 18075 D UE4 : [2017.01.19 - 00.59.11:072][-8608252]LogTemp : Warning : Execute TASK : tID 18075 | is game ? 1
```

Comment: I was doing mostly the same and was successfully to save game without any pause. 

Some differences:

Comment: 1. I was calling the default `SaveSystem->SaveGame(false, *SlotName, UserIndex, ObjectBytes);`, however the underlying logic are similar I believe, like the `FFileHelper::SaveArrayToFile()`

Comment: 2. I was only calling `FRunnableThread::Create(newInstance, TEXT("SomeName"),)`, without providing additional parameters and I gave a name.

Comment: 3. I don't see any critical section here, shoudn't `task` function be protected by lock? Since it's called by a `FRunnable::Run()` and it's multithreaded.

Comment: 4. When is the ctor of `ACard` being called? I'm not sure but maybe the timing causes the threading behavior to be different. Like creating the thread too early or something.

Comment: @MarsonMao answers: 1- I did not use UE's save slot mechanism because this is a binary video file downloaded from a server. Nothing to do with UE objects, but you are right that it uses the same save method. 2-I'll give it a try. 3-no need to lock or sync for this case; I'm just trying to get it working without blocking for a single download at this point. 4- Card is instantiated when the default map starts. But the download and subsequent save are triggered when ACard::downloadMedia() is called from a BP during gameplay. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey I checked the codes of `FRunnableThread::Create`, it won't create a thread if `FPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()` returns false. What platform are you using? The command line argument also seems to affect the threading creation if your platform doesn't specify the return value, you can check the codes of `FGenericPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()`.

Comment: I mean, if your `Run()` is actually being called, then it's very likely that `FPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()` returns false so that it's single threaded and blocks.

Comment: @MarsonMao I'm running this on GearVR. I did not understand your last comment about `Run` being called. Run SHOULD be called by the thread, if I understand the mechanics correctly.

Comment: Yes it is called by the thread, but the thread might be a "fake" thread if your platform doesn't support multi threading. Just check the source codes and maybe set a break point inside `FRunnableThread::Create` then you can understand what I'm talking about. By the way try to set the break point inside `Run()` (i.e. the line of `task();`) and see if it's running on a separate thread.

Comment: And GearVR is not a platform, I think it is running on Android platform?

Comment: If so the Android platform supports multi threading, so the thread should be created. Anyway I suggest to set the break point for `Run()` and see which thread it's running on and check the call stack. Since I can't run a GearVR project myself so that's what I've thought of. Sorry for not providing a real help :(

Comment: Ah, sorry I have to add some comment again, since Android platform is not overriding `bool FGenericPlatformProcess::SupportsMultithreading()`, so it uses the default implementation, and this function checks the command line argument to see if there's a `nothreading` argument, if so then it return false. So, I think you can also check if this is happening.

Comment: @MarsonMao hey I'm still trying to figure this out. In Visual Studio itself I can confirm that I am running on separate threads as expected. But then again this is on desktop and in the editor my code works as I'd expect. On Android however I'm not sure how to check if separate threads are being used because I cannot set breakpoints. Do you know if there is a way in Unreal to at least print the id or name of the "current" thread? I can't find anything on this.

Comment: You can try `FPlatformTLS::GetCurrentThreadId()`. There is a `IsInGameThread()` function (and many similar ones) used everywhere in UE's codebase, you can also check the source codes of them, they are in `ThreadingBase.cpp`.

Comment: @MarsonMao Sorry for the delay. Still this issue is not solved for me. I can confirm that both in Windows as well as in Android the save task does indeed get called in a separate thread, by using your suggestion of FPlatformTSL